# VS code Go to function definition not working for C code

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm using vs code for windows. I was able to shh into my remote host. However, when I hover over the function or variable it keeps loading indefinitely(also f12 or shift+f12). It is working in python code(I have the python extension installed) but not the C code (code has repositories in C and python).

I have the C/C++ extension (also tried the C/C++ extension pack) installed. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling multiple times, disconnecting and reconnecting, disabling and enabling the extension but the issue persists.